# Checking g-select mapping properties

Tags: javascript, grails

Hello I created this dropdownbox

```
  <g:select from="${[['key':1, 'value':'text1'],['key':2, 'value':'text2' else']]}" optionKey="key" optionValue="value" name="mine"/>
```

My question is how can I print the message "hi" everytime I have clicked on the text1 field

Comment: I think you have asked the same question three times in three different ways today. Javascript is your answer. Jquery or non-jquery if you wish to capture the change of your front end. In order for grails to display `Hi` the select has to be posted to a controller processed and then return hello if the select item is the one you say.  Besides posting it to a back-end or using jquery you could look into angular-js app and that has more intelligence but a little like the jquery I already mentioned. Just more intense than jquery. Will you accept this as your final answer to this puzzle ?

Comment: Don't you have a spelling inside: `['key':2, 'value':'text2' else']`? I'm talking about **else'**.

Answer (score 1):

For the `select` you can use attribute `onchange` to set the function it will call when value is changed:

```
<g:select onchange="printmsg(this)" from="${[['key':1, 'value':'text1']....
```

Then you write that function that checks the new value for the `select` and determines if it is what you are looking for.

```
printmsg = function(element) {
   var chosen = $(element).val();
   if (chosen === "text1"){
      alert("Omg. What have you done?!");
   }
}
```

Of course put Javascript in gsp page (and for this code add jquery library) as well.